# List of Strings to single String

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do this exercise in a book,

Define a function:

```
onSeperateLines :: [String] -> String
```

which takes a list of string and returns a single string which when printed shows the strings on separate lines.

I'm struggling with converting a list to a single string

```
onSeperateLines :: [String] -> String
onSeperateLines ls = [x | x <- ls]
```

I can write functions that take a String and convert it to a list and also a list that outputs a list, but I can't figure out how to take a list and convert it to a single string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `String` is nothing but a list of characters:

```
type String = [Char]
```

Hence,

```
onSeperateLines :: [[Char]] -> [Char]
```

Now, if you actually need this for some application, it's a good idea to first [ask Hoogle if there's already something there](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[[Char]]+-%3E+[Char]). You get a whole lot of results:

> `unlines :: [String] -> String` -- that's *exactly* the function you're trying to implement!
>   `unwords :: [String] -> String` -- similar, but only insert spaces, not newlines
>   `joinPath :: [FilePath] -> FilePath` -- Not relevant here
>   `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` -- this does the general task of flattening a nested list to a simple one like a string.

`concat` is a good choice if you don't just want to use a standard function for the specific task, but also don't want to make life more difficult than necessary.

Of course, it also can't hurt to write a function like that once *completely* by yourself. To do that, you'll need to recursively<sup>†</sup> *deconstruct a list*. This is extremely simple thanks to pattern matching:

```
onSeperateLines [] = ... --- no lines to concatenate... what's the result?
onSeperateLines (l:ls) = ...
 where otherLines = onSeperateLines ls
```

Think a little about what goes in these gaps.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>The equivalent solution with `foldr` is also a good excercise.</sub>

Comment: I've not used the (l:ls) notation before, if I entered a list of ["first","second","third"] how would I use 'l'  to get the last two strings because 'ls' is a list and 'l' refers to the first string in the list doesn't it?

Comment: Another good one: `intercalate`, which easily generalizes `unwords` and `unlines`.

Comment: @W22: right. That's why you do a recursive call on `ls`: in one of these calls, any line will be the `l` once!